# Remote folder on remote pc batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing, cmd, scripting

I currently install printers by going to a network location in an explorer window and typing in the location and it auto installs ex: \server\printer

I am trying to make a simple batch script that prompts user for a computername, then when they enter it, it should open up that location on that remote pc.

```
@echo off

set /p deviceid="Enter Device ID: "

EXPLORER \\%deviceid%\c$

echo Installing Printer...

EXPLORER \\server\printer
```

Currently this will bring up the C drive of the remote PC and install the printer on MY pc instead of the remote pc. I was using that just for testing purposes, but you can see what i'm trying to do.

Comment: If you are trying to remotely install something on another computer you should take a look at using Microsoft's PSEXEC utility.

Answer (score 0):

You can get PSEXEC from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx.  To use it you would want to do something like

```
set /p deviceid="Enter Device ID: "

psexec \\%deviceid% -u "username" -p "password" -i -d "\\server\printer"
```

And depending on what you're doing exactly, that will execute w.e on the device you are trying to get this installed on.  Alternatively you could make a script that will make a seperate script then execute that script after having it copied to the computer and that will install the printer.

```
@echo off

Echo Device ID
set /p deviceid=

Echo Server Name
set /p server=

Echo Printer
set /p printer=

set "out=\\%deviceid%\c$"
>  "%out%\Printer.bat" RunDll32.EXE printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n "\\%server%\%printer%"  

psexec \\%deviceid% -u "username" -p "password" -i -d "C:\Printer.bat"

timeout /t 5
```

I do believe either would work.  I am not as seasoned as most people on here but I do believe this will work.  And if your server and printer name does not change you can just set them here and not have to have them set within the script.